# Accept a blank input from C string

Tags: c++

I recieve an error if the object is left blank:

surname, mary terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Question in whole:

Write a program that reads a person’s name in the following format: first name, then middle name or initial, and then last name. The program then outputs the name in the following format:
last name, first name. middle initial.

Your program should work the same and place a full stop after the middle initial even if the input did not contain a full stop. Your program should allow for users who give no middle name or initial. In that case, the output of courses contains no middle name or initial. For example, the input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
std::string FirstName;
std::string SecondName;
std::string LastName;

getline(std::cin,FirstName);
getline(std::cin,SecondName);
getline(std::cin,LastName);
std::cout<<LastName<<", "<<FirstName<< " "<<SecondName.at(0)<<"."<< std::endl;

}
```

Comment: [Your code works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zU7p5SI4rhrWxJDy) when the character for `.at(0)` is provided. What error do you get? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If `LastName` is empty, then the actual last name will be in `SecondName`. Just do `std::swap(SecondName, LastName)`. And then you need to add a case for empty `SecondName`.

Comment: sorry editted with error - surname, mary terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' - if you leave middle name black

Comment: And you're not using C strings, `std::string` (defined in the `<string>` header) is a C++ class.

Comment: Either way, you *must* check if a string is empty or not before attempting to use any elements in it.